# Combine .sink print doesn't print

Tags: swift, aws-amplify, combine

I am new to Combine and Sink, however the prints that I put in them do not seem to log however the result of the action completes as the user is created within AWS Amplify.

```
@objc private func createAccountButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Create Account Button Action")
    signUp(password: self.password, email: self.email)
  }
  
  func signUp(password: String, email: String) -> AnyCancellable {
      let userAttributes = [AuthUserAttribute(.email, value: email)]
      let options = AuthSignUpRequest.Options(userAttributes: userAttributes)
      let sink = Amplify.Auth.signUp(username: email, password: password, options: options)
        .resultPublisher.sink(receiveCompletion: { (authError) in
          print("Failed with error: \(authError)")
        }, receiveValue: { (signUpResult) in
          print("Signed Up")
        })
    return sink
  }
```

Comment: No, I don’t get it. You return a Combine pipeline called `sink` but you never do anything with it. Did you mean to `store` it somewhere? If you don’t, your Combine pipeline never runs; it just dies instantly.

Comment: @matt, oh that explains why I cannot see the prints however I am only following the AWS Amplify tutorial and it does not know how to use the functions :( But thank you I will go explore sink and store

Comment: I know nothing of Amplify support for Combine. I’m just commenting on the incoherent nature of returning a pipeline and then just throwing it away. See my https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/start/startpipelines.html for some practical working examples.

Comment: Hitting the same issue now! These posts are very helpful. The Amplify docs are usually great, but prior knowledge to Combine framework seems implied. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `.sink` operator, it returns a token of type `AnyCancellable`. When that token is destroyed, it calls `cancel` on itself, which tears down the subscription it represents. You're not saving the token, so Swift destroys it immediately, before the subscription has had a chance to deliver any outputs.

The usual solution is to find a place to store the token, like in a property of a controller object:

```
class AccountCreationController: UIViewController {
    private var token: AnyCancellable? = nil
// NEW          ^^^^^ storage for the AnyCancellable

    @objc private func createAccountButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Create Account Button Action")
        signUp(password: self.password, email: self.email)
    }

    func signUp(password: String, email: String) {
        let userAttributes = [AuthUserAttribute(.email, value: email)]
        let options = AuthSignUpRequest.Options(userAttributes: userAttributes)
        token = Amplify.Auth.signUp(username: email, password: password, options: options)
// NEW  ^^^^^ store the AnyCancellable to keep the subscription alive
            .resultPublisher.sink(
                receiveCompletion: { (authError) in
                    print("Failed with error: \(authError)")
                },
                receiveValue: { (signUpResult) in
                    print("Signed Up")
                })
    }
}
```

An alternative, if you are sure you never want to cancel the subscription (e.g. the user cannot press a “Cancel” button to back out), is to create a `Subscribers.Sink` directly, instead of using the `sink` operator, and use the `subscribe` method to subscribe the `Sink` to the `Publisher`. The `subscribe` method does **not** return an `AnyCancellable`. The `Sink` object is itself a `Cancellable`, but not an `AnyCancellable`, and you don't have to store it anywhere to keep the subscription alive.

```
class AccountCreationController: UIViewController {
    @objc private func createAccountButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Create Account Button Action")
        signUp(password: self.password, email: self.email)
    }

    func signUp(password: String, email: String) {
        let userAttributes = [AuthUserAttribute(.email, value: email)]
        let options = AuthSignUpRequest.Options(userAttributes: userAttributes)
        Amplify.Auth.signUp(username: email, password: password, options: options)
// NEW  ^ There is no AnyCancellable to store.
            .resultPublisher
            .subscribe(
// NEW      ^^^^^^^^^^ use the subscribe method instead of sink.
                Subscribers.Sink(
// NEW          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Create a Sink object.
                    receiveCompletion: { (authError) in
                        print("Failed with error: \(authError)")
                    },
                    receiveValue: { (signUpResult) in
                        print("Signed Up")
                    }
                )
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that explanation makes so much sense and has helped massively!