# On unit test, How does assert the PassthroughSubject value without an external library?

Tags: swift, combine

Please help me, I would like to test the `viewModel`, when I'm run unit test and then an error is raised `Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 1 second`

```
var usersSubject = PassthroughSubject<[User],Error>()

    func fetchUsers(){
        let url = URL(string: endpoint.urlString)!
        apiManager.fetchItems(url: url) { (result: Result<[User],Error>)  in
            switch result {
            case .success(let users):
                self.usersSubject.send(users)
            case .failure(let error):
                self.usersSubject.send(completion: .failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    func testsuccess(){
        viewModel.usersSubject.sink { completion in
            self.exectation.fulfill()
        } receiveValue: { users in
            XCTAssertEqual(1, users.count)
            XCTAssertEqual("Hello World", users[0].name)
            self.exectation.fulfill()
        }
        
        viewModel.fetchUsers()
        XCTAssertEqual(1, apiManager.numberOfCalled)
        
        wait(for: [exectation], timeout: 1.0)
    }

    class StubApiManager: APIManager {
        var numberOfCalled = 0
        override func fetchItems<T>(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<[T], Error>) -> Void) where T : Decodable {
            let users = [
            User(id: 1, name: "Hello World")
            ]
            numberOfCalled += 1
            completion(.success(users as! [T]))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `viewModel.usersSubject.sink` **before** you call `viewModel.fetchUsers()`, so that the subscription exists when the view model calls `usersSubject.send`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm revising a test case sequential by your suggest but this not working. ```the sequential is 1. call viewModel.userSubject.sink for assert the value 2. call viewModel.fetchUser()```

Comment: You need to edit your question to show the new version of your code.

Comment: OK, I'm got it. please review again

Comment: The compiler is giving you a warning for your current code, and you're ignoring the warning. You need to pay attention to it. You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65722102/77567) for more info.